# html appengine redirect URL

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, url, redirect

I want to redirect a user to the next URL after authenticating on a third party web page. In the redirect URL I want it to contain some info about the user, i.e. session id. For example my redirect URL will be `www.z.appspot.com/?session=x/` when the user returns to my page I want to parse some of their details from the new URL, for example `www.z.appspot.com/?access_code=x/?token=y&user_id=u` but when trying to parse out the information it is unable to see the token in the URL as it takes it to be part of session. I tried using `&` but still no joy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the service you're redirecting to doesn't compose query parameters in the continue URL correctly. The easiest way around this would be (as I suggested in your original question) to send the parameter as part of the path, rather than the query string - that is, use URLs of the form:

```
http://www.yourapp.com/continue/1234
```

Where `1234` is the user's session ID or user ID.

Answer (score 1):

You want a module called cgi, and a function called FieldStorage.  Do it like this:

```
import cgi

url_parms = cgi.FieldStorage()
session = url_parms.getvalue("session","default")
```

You can do this for any of the URL parameters.  Replace "default" with whatever you want the default value to be (like an empty string).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit confusing, but is there a reason your other service can not redirect to: `www.z.appspot.com/?access_code=x/&token=y&user_id=u`?  That should be correctly parsed:

```
import urlparse
import cgi

url = "www.z.appspot.com/?access_code=x/&token=y&user_id=u"
query = urlparse.urlparse(url).query
print cgi.parse_qs(query)
# output: {'access_code': ['x/'], 'token': ['y'], 'user_id': ['u']}
```

If you can not change the format of the url, you could do something like:

```
import urlparse
import cgi

url = "www.z.appspot.com/?access_code=x/?token=y&user_id=u"
query = urlparse.urlparse(url).query
access_code, query = query.split('?', 1)
access_code = access_code.split('=', 1)[1]
print access_code
# output: 'x/'
print cgi.parse_qs(query)
# output: {'token': ['y'], 'user_id': ['u']}
```

Or, if you're just trying to ask how to embed parameters in the URL they will be redirected to, see Python's [urlencode](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode).

**Update**:

```
import urllib
encoded = urllib.urlencode({'app_id': 11,
                            'next': 'http://localhost:8086/?access_tok­en=%s' % (access_token,)})
hunch_url = 'http://hunch.com/authorize/v1/?%s' % (encoded,)
```

Then pass `hunch_url` to your template.

Comment: My user initially signs in using 4sq and then a session is created, if they are a new user I redirect them to hunch using `<form method="post" align = "left" action = "http://hunch.com/authorize/v1/?app_id=11&next=http://localhost:8086/?access_token={{access_token}}/&" >
                      <div>
                     <input type="submit" value="Login using Hunch">
             
     </div>
             </form>` and so the returned URL is as above, I already have it working with the user logging in through Hunch but not when using this new parameter. Would a CGI module be more ideal?

Comment: @Stina, You need to urlencode the next url and its parameters.  See my updated answer.