# Check if user is disabled in an appengine application using openid

Tags: google-app-engine, openid, python-2.7

I have an application written in Google App Engine (Python 2.7) where users can authenticate using OpenID. I would like to have the ability to disable access to some of those users, according to a field `disabled` which I have on a `UserProfile` table.

Is it possible to add a step to the OpenID authentication so that after the round trip to the OpenID provider the user is checked to be active before forwarding it to the value of the `continue` parameter? Or is there another workaround?

Comment: Seems that this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/5444240/336455 contains an idea for an answer. Still need to grok it though.